# Should component writes into store in React js app?

Tags: design-patterns, reactjs, flux

Is it a good idea, or is it an anti pattern, to allow direct writing into store from a React component? (without using dispatcher)

Comment: Do you have one of the flux implementations ? Redux ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Component should have **single responsibility** (one of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles) - to render UI view. If it writes to the store, this principle is violated.
2. To gain more reusability of components - it would be better to remove unnecessary dependencies. It case of direct writing to store your UI component will be dependent on the store implementation. Even better - remove dependency from dispatcher. Set callback explicitly with props:

   ```
   const Component = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return <button onClick={ this.props.onClick }></button>;
     }
   });

   <Component onClick={ callDispatcher } />
   ```

   In that case your `Component` is the most reusable. You can use it even in the different project with different 'flux' implementation.

See many good ideas in **Redux** - it removes as many dependencies as possible from components. In Redux you have all your components "dumb" / "pure" (they haven't state) and you can attach state to component via function that take component by arguments (for example, Redux's `connect`). It also called **higher-order component**.

> A higher-order component is just a function that takes an existing
>   component and returns another component that wraps it.

[See more details](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.o3rxgumk9) (from Redux author Dan Abramov).